# cannot install openx 2.8.10 localhost past register

Tags: installation, localhost, openx

Operating Windows7

I downloaded and unzipped Openx 2.8.10 into c:/wamp/www/

I started the OpenX installation into localhost and came to a screen:
Do you already have an OpenX.org account?

There were 2 Options:  I have an OpenX.org account/ I do not have an OpenX.org account

I clicked: I do not have an OpenX.org account and entered a username.

The username came up as not available.

Tried again with a different username, and again, and again. I typed in a jumble of letters and symbols. Still not available.

AHA!! I went online and registered with www.openx.org. I received an activation key via email, activated my account and successfully registered.

I started the OpenX localhost installation again.

I came to the screen:
I have an OpenX.org account I do not have an OpenX.org account

I clicked:I have an OpenX.org account (!!!)

I entered my newly registered username and password and got:
Invalid user name or password. Please check that the OpenX User name and password are correct. [Yes, I did check. I re-entered them several times.]
If you have recently signed up for a new OpenX.org account, make sure you have gone into your email and activated your OpenX.org account.

I tried again, and again but I can't get past that registration screen.

Comment: I apologise. I tried again (this is several days after the original attempt)  and, for no reason at all - nothing had changed - my registration was accepted and I have now completed the installation.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that the problem was not with the activation of the account openx.org, but with my browser Firefox 22.0a2 (with add-ons security) enabled.

My solution was to use a browser and clear light (no add-ons) that was actually the QtWeb Browser.

The installation proceeded smoothly with only QtWeb Browser.

Thank you!

Brazil

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I thought disabling ABP would work but the installation always jumped back to step 1 with Chrome. Tried Safari and it worked.